# Invoices no longer being automatically generated after switch from http:// to https:// (magento site)

Tags: magento, web, e-commerce

Since switching from HTTP to HTTPS our customers e-commerce site's orders are not automatically generating an invoice anymore, the confirmation e-mails are also not being sent. We originally thought this must be to do with Barclaycard as they are the payment gateway providers but they claim this is nothing to do with them after further inspection and said something else must have changed. I've checked through all of the config and can't see anything on the magento backend that would be causing this issue, has anyone experienced anything like this before or could help with this? Thanks.